# How to add both double quotes and triple Quotes in String header while generating CSV using CSVFormat

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons

I am trying to generate a CSV file using CSVFormat, my requirement is to add double quotes in some of the header and triple quotes in some of the header. I am able to add double quotes in the required headers but i am unable to add triple quotes in the mentioned header using CSVFormat.

Below is the example

```
"Employee Name","Job Title","Store:","""Stage of Art""",Action Required ,,External Key..etc
```

In the above example *Employee Name, Job Title* are in double quotes and *Stage of Art* is in triple quotes.
I can add double quotes in the header fields , below is the code i have written

```
try(CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(out,   CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withAllowDuplicateHeaderNames("\""+EmplyeeEnum.EMP_NAME.getHeader()+"\"","\""+EmplyeeEnum.JOB_TITLE.getHeader()+"\"","\""+EmplyeeEnum.STAGE_OF_ART.getHeader()+"\"",EmplyeeEnum.ACTION_REQUIRED.getHeader(),EmplyeeEnum.EXTERNAL_KEY.getHeader()).withEscape('\\').withQuoteMode(Quote.NONE)
```

Above code will generate output like below

```
"Employee Name","Job Title","Store:","Stage of Art",Action Required ,,External Key..etc
```

Can anyone suggest me how to solve this

Comment: Your code does not appear to compile - can you take a second look? (1) Should `Quote.NONE` actually be `QuoteMode.NONE`? (2) `withAllowDuplicateHeaderNames(...)` takes nothing, or a boolean - you have strings. Also, it would help to see the code for `EmplyeeEnum`.

Comment: Having said that, if you can create the quotes you need using `"\""`, then can you generate three such quotes using this: `"\"\"\""`? For example, see the output from `System.out.println("\"\"\"");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the expected result.

```
new CSVPrinter(w, CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                .withHeader("\"Employee Name\"","\"Job Title\"","\"Store:\"","\"\"\"Stage of Art\"\"\"","Action Required","","External Key").withEscape('\\').withQuoteMode(QuoteMode.NONE))
```

Comment: Please add details around why the quoted answer works. It helps people understand better.

Comment: @Shihan Silva for long string it is appending \ before comma